# Mac Lync Conversation History Storage Location

Tags: macos, ms-office

Anyone know where Mac Lync 2011 stores its conversation history? Since it isn't tied to Outlook, it isn't stored on the Exchange server is it? If not, I need to back it up...

Answer (score 14):

Found it!

```
/Users/<username>/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Microsoft Lync History
```

Comment: I deleted that directory but the chat history has not disappeared. You can delete history entries manually in the UI but I haven't found a way to bulk delete.